# Pandas using regex to return number if contains duplicated digits

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to analyze a large column of data that contains 12 digit numbers as seen below:

```
0    802112134267
1    300949934377
2    300999934377
3    222589009836
4    950279219923
Name: number, dtype: object
```

I want to grab any number that has 3 or more repeated characters.  Row 2 contains 4 '9's and row 3 contains 3 '2's.  I would want to return:

```
0    None
1    None
2    300999934377
3    222589009836
4    None
Name: number, dtype: object
```

Or just a truncated/filtered dataframe/series would suffice.

The regex that I think solves this is: '(\d)\1{2,}'

However, I haven't been able to successfully apply this regex to the series.

```
regex = re.compile('(\d)\1{2,}')
s.apply(lambda x: np.nan if regex.search(x) == None else x)
```

returns all NaN.

```
s.str.extract('(\d)\1{2,}', expand=True)
```

returns all NaN.

```
s.str.contains('(\d)\1{2,}')
```

returns all False.

Any help would be appreciated.  I've tried searching the forum and haven't found any good examples that have worked.

Thanks

Comment: `r'(\d)\1{2,}'`.

Answer (score 2):

@WiktorStribiżew's regex is correct. In addition to his answer, I'd like to provide you with a simpler way to filter out your column.

You can use the `df.where` function to filter out your rows:

```
In [1524]: df['Col1'] = df.where(df['Col1'].str.contains(r'(\d)\1{2,2}'), other=None)

In [1525]: df['Col1']
Out[1525]: 
0            None
1            None
2    300999934377
3    222589009836
4            None
Name: Col1, dtype: object
```

`df['Col1'].str.contains` returns a boolean mask which is then applied to the dataframe using `df.where`. `other=None` specifies that `None` should be put in place of elements that do not match your pattern.

You can skip the regex compilation, and you don't need a lambda anymore.